# Notifying The Server On Image Upload Azure Blob

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, express, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to build a Image Upload System with Node and Azure Blob Storage. I have decided to use the Azure Blob Browser JS SDK to upload image . I have a dilemma in the above process .How do I tell the server of the blob name . I thought of the following approach but this has several problems:

> Let just say I give the blob a uuid and send the same uuid to the server but the client JS can be changed and the real blob name and the one sent to the server can differ

It might be that my approach is completely trash. Please reply ,I am a newbie to web development

Comment: While this question is rather broad (there are lots of ways to implement something like this), I'd suggest reading up on event Grid, which has the ability to send notifications whenever a new blob shows up. This could help...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I’m doing something similar in ASP.NET and SQL where I actually store the blob itself in Azure storage BUT in a SQL table it’s really just a row of meta-data, where each image has an internal numerical seed ID, a “user-defined” name (which does not have to be unique across the system), and the GUID for e blob name stored in Azure.